# espresso check toast message for partial message text

Tags: android, toast, android-espresso

I need to espresso check a toast message pop up when user click on a button. eg. it will either show 'added to favorite' or 'remove from favorite', the strings which are below from string.xml. The toast message might varies, so i can only check if the toast message containString...  Below i added the espresso code i tried but it does not work.  Anyone has better idea?

```
onView(withText(containsString("added to favorite"))).inRoot(withDecorView(not(mActivityTestRule.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));

//string.xml
<string name="message_add_favorite">%1$s %2$s added to favorite.</string>
    <string name="message_remove_favorite">%1$s %2$s removed from favorite</string>

//logcat
Started running tests

android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with text: a string containing "added to favorite"

View Hierarchy:
+>LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=749, height=129, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
|
+->AppCompatTextView{id=16908299, res-name=message, visibility=VISIBLE, width=669, height=49, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=40.0, y=40.0, text=Pizza Smith @ Galaxis removed from favourites, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
|
at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:580)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:92)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:158)
at com.korvac.liquid.presentation.intro.DiscountTest.test_08FavoriteTest(DiscountTest.java:161)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1846)
```

Comment: what exactly does not work? which exception do you get? (I tried it in a demo app and it seems to work just fine)

Comment: @stamanuel add in logcat, during the test, i can see the toast message with xxx added to favorite pop up

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `onView(allOf(withText(containsString("added to favorite")))).check(matches(isDisplayed()));`